# XML parsing to UITextView?

Tags: iphone, xml, text, sdk, rss

I am doing a simple rss-reader for a blog. But I don't know how to view the blog posts content in a UITextView. For now I can just open them in safari browser and see them there. Would be nicer to have them a little bit more native. 
So how can I place a blogpost (xml) in a UITextView? Thanks in advance.

---

Jacob L

Comment: What kind of formatting are you looking for?

Comment: Do you want to parse the xml and show them?

Comment: I want to show a Wordpress blog post in an UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to show the content of your articles in a UIWebview, and format it on server side?

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString: http://url_to_your/article.php?id=26];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: theURL];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,300)];
[webView setDelegate: self];
[webView loadRequest: request];
```

Comment: Ok, thanks but I want the blogpost to be as readable as possible. I can't format the article because it has to be like it is now.